# Exception stopping while loop in JAVA

Tags: java, exception

Below is the code to read items out of txt file and determine if the transaction is verified or not.
I am having an issue, when its throws the exception for incorrect format, it jumps out of the while loop, and then ends the program. How can I have it throw the exception but continue the loop afterwards. I did look and someone had shown having a try block for each handle, I just wanted to know if there was a better/cleaner more efficient way.

```
/*
 * @Author: Louis Krueger
 * @Desc: Homework assignment #2 exception handling
 * @Version: 1.1
 */

package paymentApplication;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainHandle {

        public static ArrayList<String> saPaymentList  = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean bSkipTrans = false;
        String sFileName = "";
        String sPaymentInfo = "";
        String[] saPaymentInfo = null;
        Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Payment> alPayments = new ArrayList<Payment>();

        try{
            System.out.println("Enter the file name to be read: ");
            sFileName = keyBoard.nextLine();
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("details.txt"));
            System.out.println("Test1");
            //loop to Create arraylist of PaymentInfo objects
            while(inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
                bSkipTrans = false;
                Payment Payment = new Payment();
                sPaymentInfo = inputStream.nextLine();
                saPaymentInfo = sPaymentInfo.split(";");
                if(saPaymentInfo.length == 1){
                    bSkipTrans = true;
                    throw new InvalidTransactionException();
                }else{
                    if(saPaymentInfo.length > 1){
                        if (isInteger(saPaymentInfo[1]) == true){
                            Payment.setiTransValue(Integer.parseInt(saPaymentInfo[1]));
                        }else{
                            //throw exception
                            bSkipTrans = true;
                            throw new InvalidTransactionException("Error#1");
                        }
                    }
                    if(saPaymentInfo.length > 4){
                    Payment.setsCreditNumber(saPaymentInfo[4]);
                    }
                    if(saPaymentInfo.length > 3){
                    Payment.setsDate(saPaymentInfo[3]);
                    }
                    if(saPaymentInfo.length > 2){
                    Payment.setsName(saPaymentInfo[2]);
                    }
                    if(saPaymentInfo.length > 0){
                        if(saPaymentInfo[0] != "Cash"|saPaymentInfo[0] != "Credit"){
                            //throws exception
                            Payment.setsTransType(saPaymentInfo[0]);
                        }else{
                            bSkipTrans = true;
                            throw new InvalidTransactionException("Error#2");
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(bSkipTrans == true){
                    //throw exception
                    bSkipTrans = true;
                    throw new InvalidTransactionException("Empty line");
                }else{
                    System.out.println(Payment.toString());
                    System.out.println("Payment Added");
                    System.out.println("-------------");
                    alPayments.add(Payment);
                }
            }
            inputStream.close();
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Error 1 has occured: " + e.getMessage());
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidTransactionException e) {
            System.out.println("InvalidTransactionException thrown");
        }finally{
            System.out.println("Finally statement reached");
            keyBoard.close();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
        try { 
            Integer.parseInt(s); 
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
            return false; 
        }
        // only got here if we didn't return false
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Put try inside the while loop so that after catching exception the loop still continues

Comment: You cannot throw an exception *and* continue, choose one or the other. If you want to continue then just log an error.

Comment: Exception means something goes wrong in the program and you have to handle it. If it doesn't matter, just eat it and log the issue otherwise you'd better deal with it and then continue or propagate it to the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a try catch inside the while loop:

```
/*
 * @Author: Louis Krueger
 * @Desc: Homework assignment #2 exception handling
 * @Version: 1.1
 */

package paymentApplication;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainHandle {

        public static ArrayList<String> saPaymentList  = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean bSkipTrans = false;
        String sFileName = "";
        String sPaymentInfo = "";
        String[] saPaymentInfo = null;
        Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Payment> alPayments = new ArrayList<Payment>();

        try{
            System.out.println("Enter the file name to be read: ");
            sFileName = keyBoard.nextLine();
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("details.txt"));
            System.out.println("Test1");
            //loop to Create arraylist of PaymentInfo objects
            while(inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
                try{
                    bSkipTrans = false;
                    Payment Payment = new Payment();
                    sPaymentInfo = inputStream.nextLine();
                    saPaymentInfo = sPaymentInfo.split(";");
                    if(saPaymentInfo.length == 1){
                        bSkipTrans = true;
                        throw new InvalidTransactionException();
                    }else{
                        if(saPaymentInfo.length > 1){
                            if (isInteger(saPaymentInfo[1]) == true){
                                Payment.setiTransValue(Integer.parseInt(saPaymentInfo[1]));
                            }else{
                                //throw exception
                                bSkipTrans = true;
                                throw new InvalidTransactionException("Error#1");
                            }
                        }
                        if(saPaymentInfo.length > 4){
                        Payment.setsCreditNumber(saPaymentInfo[4]);
                        }
                        if(saPaymentInfo.length > 3){
                        Payment.setsDate(saPaymentInfo[3]);
                        }
                        if(saPaymentInfo.length > 2){
                        Payment.setsName(saPaymentInfo[2]);
                        }
                        if(saPaymentInfo.length > 0){
                            if(saPaymentInfo[0] != "Cash"|saPaymentInfo[0] != "Credit"){
                                //throws exception
                                Payment.setsTransType(saPaymentInfo[0]);
                            }else{
                                bSkipTrans = true;
                                throw new InvalidTransactionException("Error#2");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(bSkipTrans == true){
                        //throw exception
                        bSkipTrans = true;
                        throw new InvalidTransactionException("Empty line");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println(Payment.toString());
                        System.out.println("Payment Added");
                        System.out.println("-------------");
                        alPayments.add(Payment);
                    }

                } catch (InvalidTransactionException e) {
                    System.out.println("InvalidTransactionException thrown");
                }
            }

            inputStream.close();
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Error 1 has occured: " + e.getMessage());
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        finally{
            System.out.println("Finally statement reached");
            keyBoard.close();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
        try { 
            Integer.parseInt(s); 
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
            return false; 
        }
        // only got here if we didn't return false
        return true;
    }

}
```